# How to make synchronism between two distinct C programs?

Tags: c, system-calls, systems-programming

First of all, I don't know if I can explain well my problem or you can get it in the appropriate way. But I will try to make it clear for you.

In fact, I have two different C programs.
The first one is a simple loop print of a message on the console :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ()
{
    while(1)
        {
        printf("WAITING\n");
        sleep(1);
        }
}
```

The second one is a blocking program that waits for an event ( press button ) to turn on led in my embedded board.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <linux/input.h>

#define BTN_FILE_PATH "/dev/input/event0"
#define LED_PATH "/sys/class/leds"

#define green "green"

void change_led_state(char *led_path, int led_value)
{
    char    lpath[64];
    FILE    *led_fd;

    strncpy(lpath, led_path, sizeof(lpath) - 1);
    lpath[sizeof(lpath) - 1] = '\0';

    led_fd = fopen(lpath, "w");

    if (led_fd == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "simplekey: unable to access led\n");
        return;
    }

    fprintf(led_fd, "%d\n", led_value);

    fclose(led_fd);
}

void reset_leds(void)
{

    change_led_state(LED_PATH "/" green "/brightness", 0);
}

int configure_leds(void)
{
    FILE    *l_fd;
    FILE    *r_fd;
    char    *none_str = "none";

    /* Configure leds for hand control */

    r_fd = fopen(LED_PATH "/" green "/trigger", "w");




    fprintf(r_fd, "%s\n", none_str);


    fclose(r_fd);


    /* Switch off leds */
    reset_leds();

    return 0;
}

void eval_keycode(int code)
{

    static int green_state = 0;

    switch (code) {
    case 260:
        printf("BTN left pressed\n");

        /* figure out red state */

        green_state = green_state ? 0 : 1;

        change_led_state(LED_PATH "/" green "/brightness", green_state);
        break;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    int file;
    /* how many bytes were read */
    size_t  rb;
    int ret;
    int yalv;
    /* the events (up to 64 at once) */
    struct input_event  ev[64];
    char    *str = BTN_FILE_PATH;

    printf("Starting simplekey app\n");

    ret = configure_leds();
    if (ret < 0)
        exit(1);

    printf("File Path: %s\n", str);

    if((file = open(str, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
        perror("simplekey: File can not open");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (;;) {
        /* Blocking read */
        rb= read(file, &ev, sizeof(ev));

        if (rb < (int) sizeof(struct input_event)) {
            perror("simplekey: short read");
            exit(1);
        }

        for (yalv = 0;
            yalv < (int) (rb / sizeof(struct input_event));
            yalv++) {
            if (ev[yalv].type == EV_KEY) {
                printf("%ld.%06ld ",
                    ev[yalv].time.tv_sec,
                    ev[yalv].time.tv_usec);
                printf("type %d code %d value %d\n",
                        ev[yalv].type,
                        ev[yalv].code, ev[yalv].value);

                /* Change state on button pressed */
                if (ev[yalv].value == 0)
                    eval_keycode(ev[yalv].code);
            }
        }
    }

    close(file);
    reset_leds();
    exit(0);
}
```

When I execute the second code, the program **starts waiting for the event** to switch on/off the led.

My question is :

How can I make interaction between the two programs ? I want to execute the firs one --> It starts printing for me " WAITING " until I press the BUTTON --> the LED turn on --> and then it goes back to the first program and re-start printing " WAITING " on the console.

I don't know if I explained well the issue but I hope that you can help me! Thank you.

Comment: Is there any reason these have to be different processes ?

Comment: This problem is a simple example for a future work. We are developing an operating system ..

Comment: _We are developing and operating system._    That may be a little ambitious if you do not yet have ideas about _[inter-process communication](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/inter_process_communication/inter_process_communication_tutorial.pdf)_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a communication mechanism between your two programs. This is also known als [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Generally, you have several options to achieve this (depending on the operating system you are using, not all of them may be available):

- Shared memory / shared files
- Message passing (e.g. via sockets)
- Pipes
- Signals

A helpful introduction can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inter-process-communication-ipc/).

Comment: I am using Linux OS.

Comment: Thank you. I read what is described in the two links but I still don't know how to do this in my code. I think that i need a concrete example.

Comment: @gaston - The links provided here, and in comments under your post provide _concrete examples_.  If you want someone to do more than point you to example code with this type of question, you do not yet understand  the scope of a good question on this site.  Take a minute to read these: _[What kind of questions should not be asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_.  _[Questions in scope for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_.